# fire an publisher after another

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I want to fire two publishers but second should only fire when first one is complete. I tried it with zip could not achieve it. Following is my code:

```
    let resetPasscodeConfirmationPublisher = authUseCase.resetPasscodeConfirmation(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, code: pincode, passcode: passcode)
        
    
    let getAuthTokenPublisher = authUseCase.getAccessToken(passcode: passcode)
        
        resetPasscodeConfirmationPublisher.zip(getAuthTokenPublisher).sink { res in
            print(res)
        } receiveValue: { values in
            print(values.0)
            print(values.1)
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
```

so first, resetPasscodeConfirmationPublisher should run and when it is done and I get some value from it getAuthTokenPublisher should run. Right now I am getting response from getAuthTokenPublisher only and not from the first publisher.

Comment: Use `flatMap`: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map operator to do that

```swift
resetPasscodeConfirmationPublisher
    .map { result in
        // do what you need with the result
        return getAuthTokenPublisher
    }
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { completion in

        },
        receiveValue: { value in

        }
    )
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Don't know why someone down voted your answer but I loved it as it worked great for me. Thanks you